# Pandas merge by name and date (multiple columns)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multiple-columns

I am looking to merge two data frames, first by name and then by date.

df 1 looks like this

```
symbol. X.  X.  X.  X. date
AA.                    2018-01-16
AA.                    2018-05-04
....
```

then df2

```
symbol.  X.  X.  X. X. date
AA.                   2018-01-03
AA.                   2018-01-03
```

I have tried many variations of the following:

```
data = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = ['symbol', 'date'], how = 'left')
```

All I want to do is a left join where the data comes out:

```
symbol.  X.  X. X. date
AA.                2018-01-03
AA.                2018-01-04
....
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated​, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here

Comment: please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Provide more information. How did the second row in your expected output suddenly changed to `2018-01-04`?

Answer (score 2):

To merge two dataframes by multiple columns you can use

```
data = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['symbol','date'], how='left')
```

If the columns have different names, you can also use

```
data = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['symbol','date'], right_on=['symbol_2','date_2'], how='left')
```

Hope that can help you :)

Comment: When I use that, my right side is all nulls. Does this mean that there is an issue with the dates?

Comment: Okay so here is what I did, I went back and used

    df1['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
    df2['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
This way I had the same data types/structure going all the way through. I also used an inner join as I am looking for the similarities (please advise if I should use an outer?) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To merge dataframes in your situation, you can try this

```
dfFinal = df2.merge(df1[['Symbol']], on='Symbol', how='outer')
```

Comment: should I not use an inner join? I am trying to match up the similar data points and drop non-matching records

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is what I did, I went back and used

```
df1['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
df2['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
```

This way I had the same data types/structure going all the way through. I also used an inner join as I am looking for the similarities (please advise if I should use an outer?)